# Chinese character UTF-16 Encoding string in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I am trying to encode string in java using following method,

```
String s = "子";
byte[]   bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(s.getBytes("UTF-16"));
String stringEncoded = new String(bytesEncoded);
```

When I run this code in eclipse I am getting value as /v9bUA==

But some online UTF 16 converter giving values like **4E02**

Anybody knows how to convert Chinese characters in UTF 16.

I already gone through most of stackoverflow question still got no answers.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think you should add ISO8859-1 to your string like: String string1 = new String(encoding1, "ISO8859-1");

Comment: Sounds like either the converter has a bug or you're misusing it. If you don't share *which* converter you used it's pretty hard for anyone to replicate your results, don't you think?

Comment: Also `4E02` looks like hex, not Base64. Why are you Base64-encoding the Java string?

Comment: Are you sure you're even looking at the right character on this mysterious converter site? [U+4E02](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4E02/index.htm) is `丂`, not `子` - that's [U+5B50](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5B50/index.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine.

You just need to convert bytecode in to hex representation,

```
String encodeAsUcs2(String messageContent) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  byte[] bytes = messageContent.getBytes("UTF-16BE");

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
  }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
String s = "子";
byte[] utf16encodedBytes = s.getBytes("UTF-16")
```

will give you the string encoded as uft16 bytes.

I think what is confusing you here is that you are then encoding to Base64 which gives those bytes in ASCII as **/v9bUA==**.  The number **4E02** is a Hex encoding. To see the Hex encoding for your example you could try:

```
String hexEncodedString =  DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(utf16encodedBytes);
```